# How to prevent Firefox animation/transition jump

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

Today I noticed a rather annyoing bug in Firefox.

When you apply a CSS animation to an element and also a transition that targets the same keys (e.g. `transition: all`), the animation stutters / jumps / restarts / runs twice.

I compiled [a quick demo](http://codepen.io/silvinci/pen/dwuqs). In all browsers, except Firefox, the bar slides down as intended. Only Firefox stutters, because of the transition.

Is this a known bug? Is there a *clever* way to circumvent this? I don't want to start writing browser-specific stylesheets again. Is there a JavaScript drop in?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is a bug at all... I couldn't find a place in the spec where it would say one or another. Anyway, did you search for and/or [file a bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi)?

Anyway, the workaround is not to use `all`, which does trigger on the positional changes as well, that are happening due to the `animation`, but use something more specific. E.g. in your demo use

```
transition: background .5s ease
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Donfk